# Showing zeroes in sql count

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I`m using redshift and trying to count different things by days, but its not showing when the count in table 2 is zero. How can i make it show count zero?

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(date1,'dd') AS day,
       COUNT(*) as Volume,sum(CASE WHEN status = 'ANSWERED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )as ANSWERED , t2.Volume AS TRANSFERS
FROM table1 t1
  RIGHT JOIN (SELECT TO_CHAR(date2,'dd') AS day,
                     COUNT(*) as Volume
              FROM table2
              WHERE TO_CHAR(date2,'yyyy_MM') IN (SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(date2,'yyyy_MM')
                                                FROM table2
                                                WHERE date2 BETWEEN DATE ('2016-11-01') AND DATE ('2016-12-30'))
              AND   type = 'Active'
              GROUP BY day) t2 ON  TO_CHAR(date1,'dd') = day
WHERE TO_CHAR(date1,'yyyy_MM') IN (SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(date1,'yyyy_MM')
                                             FROM table1
                                             WHERE date1 BETWEEN DATE ('2016-11-01') AND DATE ('2016-12-30'))
GROUP BY 1,4
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Have, you tried an outer join?

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `distinct` in the sub-query for an `IN` is useless

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you used a right join between the tables. This means that any row from the first table that doesn't have a matching day in the second table will not display.
[If you're new with SQL joins you can refer to this image that explains it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNgdq.png)

If your first (or left table) contains all of the unique days that should show up in the result, just switch the "right" to a "left" join.

Comment: Both table have days that might be 0 so this wouldnt solve the problem. I need to change this query so that the day will show up even when both tables are zero.